# I would like to pass the duns number as a parameter to another apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration

I am trying to display search results from a third party database on a visualforce page and then within the results table, select a record and create record in salesforce based off the duns number on the selected row. So far, I have been able to show an alert when the button is checked, but I am not able to pass it to a controller. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

```
public class clsDNBLookup {

    public String CUST_NAME{ get; set; }
    public String CUST_ADDRESS{ get; set; }
    public String CUST_CTRY { get; set; }
    public String CUST_NAME1{ get; set; }
    public String CUST_ADDRESS1{ get; set; }
    public String CUST_CTRY1 { get; set; }
    public String SearchTable{ get; set; }
    public String REG_NUM {get; set;}
    public String REG_NUM1 {get; set;}
    public String DUNS {get; set;}
    public List<Account>updateAccount {get; set;}
    public String ALL {get; set;}
    
    public clsDNBLookup () {

    CUST_NAME = CUST_NAME1;
    CUST_ADDRESS = CUST_ADDRESS1;
    CUST_CTRY = CUST_CTRY1;
    REG_NUM = REG_NUM1;
    }
    
   public clsDNBLookup(ApexPages.StandardController s) {
        updateAccount = [select DUNS_Number__c,Name from Account order by Name];
    }
    
    public void DNBLookup() {
    try{
          Http h = new Http();
          HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
          req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
          req.setMethod('GET');
          req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
          String sUrl = 'https://plus.dnb.com/v1/match/cleanseMatch?name=' + CUST_NAME + '&streetAddressLine1=' + CUST_ADDRESS + '&countryISOAlpha2Code=' + CUST_CTRY + '&registrationNumber='+ REG_NUM;
          sUrl = sUrl.replace(' ','%20');
          req.setEndpoint(sUrl);
          HttpResponse hresp = h.send(req);
          Root wResp = (Root) JSON.deserialize(hresp.getBody(), Root.class);
          JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(hresp.getBody());
          while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
          if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                (parser.getText() == 'duns')) {
           DUNS = parser.getText();
           system.debug(DUNS);
        
          SearchTable = '<table border="1" width="100%"><tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Registration Number</td></tr>';
          for(integer i=0;i<wResp.candidatesMatchedQuantity;i++)
          {
          SearchTable = SearchTable + '<tr><td><input type= "radio" id="mysubmitw" value = '+wResp.matchCandidates[i].organization.duns+' onclick="alert(\'DUNS Chosen is: ' + wResp.matchCandidates[i].organization.duns + '\');">Credit Request</button></td><td>' + wResp.matchCandidates[i].organization.primaryName+ '</td><td>' + wResp.matchCandidates[i].organization.primaryAddress.streetAddress.line1+'</td><td>' + wResp.matchCandidates[i].organization.registrationNumbers + '</td></tr>';
                     
          }
          SearchTable = SearchTable+ '</table>';
        }
          }
    }
        catch(DmlException e)
        {SearchTable = e.getMessage();}
    }

    public class TransactionDetail {
        public String transactionID { get; set; }
        public DateTime transactionTimestamp { get; set; }
        public String inLanguage { get; set; }
        public String serviceVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class StreetAddressLine
    {
        public String line1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public String countryISOAlpha2Code { get; set; }
        public StreetAddressLine streetAddressLine { get; set; }
    }

    public class InquiryDetail
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
    }

    public class OperatingStatus
    {
        public String description { get; set; }
        public Integer dnbCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class DunsControlStatus
    {
        public OperatingStatus operatingStatus { get; set; }
        public Boolean isMailUndeliverable { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class TradeStyleNames

    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public integer priority { get; set; }

    }

    public class Telephone
    {
        public String telephoneNumber { get; set; }
        public Boolean isUnreachable { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressCountry
    {
        public String isoAlpha2Code { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressLocality
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressRegion
    {
    }

    public class StreetAddress
    {
        public String line1 { get; set; }
        public String line2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrimaryAddress
    {
        public AddressCountry addressCountry { get; set; }
        public AddressLocality addressLocality { get; set; }
        public AddressRegion addressRegion { get; set; }
        public String postalCode { get; set; }
        public String postalCodeExtension { get; set; }
        public StreetAddress streetAddress { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class WebsiteAddress {
        public String url {get;set;} 
        public String domainName {get;set;} 

    }
    public class MailingAddress
    {
        public AddressCountry addressCountry { get; set; }
        public AddressLocality addressLocality { get; set; }
        public AddressRegion addressRegion { get; set; }
        public String postalCode { get; set; }
        public String postalCodeExtension { get; set; }
        public StreetAddress streetAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegistrationNumber
    {
        public String registrationNumber { get; set; }
        public String typeDescription { get; set; }
        public Integer typeDnBCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class MostSeniorPrincipal
    {
        public String fullName { get; set; }
    }

    public class FamilytreeRolesPlayed
    {
        public String description { get; set; }
        public Integer dnbCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class CorporateLinkage
    {
        public List<FamilytreeRolesPlayed> familytreeRolesPlayed { get; set; }
    }

    public class Organization
    {
        public String duns { get; set; }
        public List<websiteAddress> websiteAddress { get; set; }
        public DunsControlStatus dunsControlStatus { get; set; }
        public String primaryName { get; set; }
        public List<tradeStyleNames> tradeStyleNames { get; set; }
        public List<Telephone> telephone { get; set; }
        public PrimaryAddress primaryAddress { get; set; }
        public MailingAddress mailingAddress { get; set; }
        public List<RegistrationNumber> registrationNumbers { get; set; }
        public List<MostSeniorPrincipal> mostSeniorPrincipals { get; set; }
        public Boolean isStandalone { get; set; }
        public CorporateLinkage corporateLinkage { get; set; }
    }

    public class MatchGradeComponent
    {
        public String componentType { get; set; }
        public String componentRating { get; set; }
    }

    public class MatchDataProfileComponent
    {
        public String componentType { get; set; }
        public String componentValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class MatchQualityInformation
    {
        public Integer confidenceCode { get; set; }
        public String matchGrade { get; set; }
        public Integer matchGradeComponentsCount { get; set; }
        public List<MatchGradeComponent> matchGradeComponents { get; set; }
        public String matchDataProfile { get; set; }
        public Integer matchDataProfileComponentsCount { get; set; }
        public List<MatchDataProfileComponent> matchDataProfileComponents { get; set; }
        public double nameMatchScore { get; set; }
    }

    public class MatchCandidate
    {
        public Integer displaySequence { get; set; }
        public Organization organization { get; set; }
        public MatchQualityInformation matchQualityInformation { get; set; }
    }

    public class CleanseAndStandardizeInformation
    {
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public TransactionDetail transactionDetail { get; set; }
        public InquiryDetail inquiryDetail { get; set; }
        public Integer candidatesMatchedQuantity { get; set; }
        public String matchDataCriteria { get; set; }
        public List<MatchCandidate> matchCandidates { get; set; }
        public CleanseAndStandardizeInformation cleanseAndStandardizeInformation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardcontroller="Account" extensions="clsDNBLookup,AccountSelectClassController,clsDNBBlocks" title="DNB Search">

<apex:form>
  
<apex:pageBlock title="Company Details" id="CompanyLookupBlock">

    <table>
 
<tr><td>Company Name: </td><td><apex:outputText id="CUST_NAME"  value="{!account.Name}"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country Code: </td><td><apex:outputText id="CUST_CTRY"  value="{!account.BillingCountry}"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Registration Number: </td><td><apex:outputText id="REG_NUM" value="{!account.company_registration_number__c}"/></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><apex:commandButton action="{!DNBLookup}" value="Search for the company" reRender="CompanyLookupBlock">
<apex:param name="p1" value="{!CUST_NAME}" assignTo="{!CUST_NAME1}" />
<apex:param name="p2" value="{!CUST_ADDRESS}" assignTo="{!CUST_ADDRESS1}" />
<apex:param name="p3" value="{!CUST_CTRY}" assignTo="{!CUST_CTRY1}" />
    <apex:param name="p4" value="{!REG_NUM}" assignTo="{!REG_NUM1}"/>
    
</apex:commandButton></td></tr>
    </table>

<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!}"/>

<apex:outputText value="{!SearchTable}" escape="false" />
  
 &nbsp;

<tr><td>&nbsp;Update DUNS Number</td><td><apex:outputText value="{!DUNS}"/></td></tr>
   
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Felix van Hove

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I am in a fix